# C++ SetWindowText not working

Tags: c++, winapi

i'm trying to change the text in a textbox but the code doesn't seem to work.
i'm using SetWindowText(hwnd, lpcstr); and have no idea of what the problem might be

tried everything that came to my mind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
enum { ID_LABEL = 1,ID_LONG_TEXT,ID_EDIT,ID_EDIT_1,ID_BUTTON };

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nCmdShow)
{
// Creo la finestra

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("Draw");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Draw");

WNDCLASSEX wcex;

wcex.cbSize      = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style       = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra  = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra  = 0;
wcex.hInstance   = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon       = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
wcex.hCursor     = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
               _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
               _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
               NULL);

    return 1;
}

HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
    szWindowClass,
    szTitle,
    WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    450, 600,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

if(!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
               _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
               _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
               NULL);

    return 1;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

MSG msg;

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
TCHAR primo[] = _T("Inserisci la lunghezza della parola da indovinare:");
TCHAR secondo[] = _T("Inserisci le lettere (una dopo l'altra senza ne spazi ne invii):");
HDC hdc;
//HFONT hFont;
HWND button;
HWND edit;
HWND edit_1;
HWND long_edit;
HINSTANCE g_hInst;

switch(uMsg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        edit = CreateWindow("Edit", "1h2f3d4",
                             WS_BORDER |WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                             5, 30, 23, 20, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_EDIT, NULL, NULL);

        edit_1 = CreateWindow("Edit", "sdgf",
                              WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                              5, 85, 250, 20, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_EDIT_1, NULL, NULL);

        // Creo il pulsante

        button = CreateWindow("Button","Calcola",
                              BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                              260, 85, 150, 20,hWnd,(HMENU) ID_BUTTON,NULL,NULL);   

        long_edit = CreateWindow("Edit", "kjvh",
                                 WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                 5, 125, 250, 300, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_LONG_TEXT, NULL, NULL);
    }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,0));
        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,255,255));

        TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, primo, sizeof(primo));
        TextOut(hdc, 5, 60, secondo, sizeof(secondo));

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        if(edit_1 == NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Errore", "Errore", uMsg);
        }

        if(LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "sgf", "ghgfrore", uMsg);
            SetWindowText(edit_1, "lool");
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

i've posted all my code, you can see for yourself, but i don't find any problem in it

Comment: Your question is missing the obvious, how do you declare and obtain `edit_1`?

Comment: sorry, but the forum gave me some problem for posting the whole file, however

edit_1 = CreateWindow("Edit", "sdgf",
       WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
       5, 85, 250, 20, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_EDIT_1, NULL, NULL);

Comment: 1. Are you sure that `CreateWindow` succeeded? 2. Are you sure you're going down the path that calls `SetWindowText`? 3. Did you check whether `SetWindowText` returns failure and whether it sets an error code?

Comment: it gave me the button on the form so i assumed it was working as it should have... i'm checking now

Comment: ok i checked and it does not return null, so i assume it works properly

Comment: @DomeWTF: Please see my edit to your code. Is that correct?

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't know you could change my code

i have previously declared edit_1 as HWND but i tried anyway to declare it a second time as you corrected, but it doesn't work, if i declare it only when you told me to, CreateWindow returns NULL, if i duble declare it, it just doesn't work as well (not returning NULL)

Comment: Instead of "Button" use BUTTON (all caps, no quote). I think your problem is that you never reaching the SetWindowText code

Comment: it says BUTTON is undeclared as in fact it isn't..

Comment: actually, "button" is the button, edit_1 is the textbox i want to put the text into, i changed the code to what i have on my desktop

Comment: The code you show here seems correct. I suspect your problem is elsewehre: namely, that you never receive the WM_COMMAND. What event occurs (i.e. what do you do) that should cause the button text to change? Can you show us the code that handles that?

Comment: You create the children windows in the WM_PAINT handler??? Very bad idea! Use WM_CREATE for that.

Comment: i added the WM_COMMAND, now (as before) it shows both the "Errore" messagebox and the "sgf" msgbox and after the "sgf" it should process the SetWindowText

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have `edit_1` declared in more than one scope.  You declare a local one when you create the button, but notice that's in a different brace block than the reference.  Thus you probably have a separate variable named `edit_1` that isn't initialized.

**UPDATE**:  Your updated code is slightly different than the original, but the problem still exists.  `edit_1` is declared in WndProc, but it is only initialized during `WM_CREATE` callback.  When the `WM_COMMAND` callback happens (a separate call to `WndProc`), it is uninitialized, so your `SetWindowText` call goes to a random window or, more likely, nowhere.

I suggest that you use a framework that makes it easy to keep variables associated with a Window.  Obvious choices would be MFC or ATL.  You probably also need a little tutoring on C++ in order to understand scope, local versus global variables, etc.

Short of using a framework, you could probably get this code working by making the variables global, but that won't scale to anything larger than very simple programs.

Comment: i have declared edit_1 on top of CALLBACK function, i should be able to use that variable in a switch, am i wrong?

Comment: @DomeWTF, a local variable will be reinitialized every time you enter a function. If this is a message loop that you never leave it might work, but you say it's a callback. You need to make the variable a member of a class, or worst case static.

Comment: it's WndProc, i don't think i'm ever leaving it... i'm wrong?

Comment: @DomeWTF: Wrong, the WndProc function is called once per message your window receives.

Comment: Thank you i declared the variables on top of all the code as global ones and it actually works

Comment: @DomeWTF If you don't feel like toting around that window handle in some global, perhaps [`SetDlgItemText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521(v=vs.85).aspx) would be a better fit for you, which allows you to use your IDC_EDIT_1 and the parent window handle (which you get for free in your callback) to set the control text.